# Show that there is only one root in $(0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that there is only one root in $(0, \infty)$ for the following equation:

$$
\tanh(x) = \left[ \tanh\left( \frac{x}{q-1}\right) \right]^{p-1}
$$
where $1 < p < 2$ and $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

Is there a way to show this?

Comment: Hint: Take its logarithm.

Comment: @Lucian Could you elaborate, please? Do you mean that since you have two functions of logarithms they must intersect at most one point? In that case... we have a composition with $\tanh$ that I am not sure that you could overlook.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1 \iff q=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}}=\frac{p}{p-1}$, then $q-1=\frac{1}{p-1}$, so, for $x\in (0,\infty)$
\begin{align}
\tanh(x)=\tanh \left(\frac{x}{q-1}\right)^{p-1}  \iff  \tanh(x)  &=\tanh \left[(p-1)x\right]^{p-1} \\
x  &= \left[(p-1)x\right]^{p-1} \quad \text{cause tanh is 1 to 1 in $(0,\infty)$} \\
\ln x &= (p-1)\ln (p-1)+(p-1)\ln x \\
[1-(p-1)]\ln x &=  (p-1)\ln (p-1) \\
\ln x &=\frac{p-1}{2-p}\ln(p-1) \\
x&=(p-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2-p}}
\end{align}
Therefore, $x=(p-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2-p}}$ is the unique root of $\tanh(x)=\tanh \left(\frac{x}{q-1}\right)^{p-1}$ in the interval $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Oops, sorry but I meant $\left[ \tanh \left( \frac{x}{q-1} \right) \right]^{p-1}$. Will edit this... Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by differentiating with respect to $\alpha := 1/(p-1)$.